# How to iterate through a list and compare each character with each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, character

Basically, I wish to compare every character of a string inside the list and how many times it repeats.
My approach to this was to use a for or while loop but the first problem with that is the index gets out of bound if I compare `i == i+1` and the 2nd issue is that even if this miraculously works then it would compare every character in the indexes ahead again too so it would disturb my count.
I want to check if each character has an equal or odd number of occurrences in the list
e.g
`list=["BACCUBAU"]` this has an equal number of occurrences of each character in the list

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @Guy i dont have a complete code yet its just some rough loops in my notebook

Comment: So do you want to know if all characters of the string are equal? And, if this is not the case, how would you compare them?

Comment: @XxJames07- I wanna know if all the characters in the list have an equal or odd amount of occurrences in the list

Comment: @jack_green, it would be better if you could include the code along with some sample input & expected output.

Comment: So, do you have a list of characters(strings with lenght 1) or a list of strings with more than one character?

Comment: I don't understand: do you have a _string_, a _list_, or a _list of strings_ ?

Comment: You should be utilising the Counter class from the *collections* module

Comment: @Vlad only if he is using a string or list of characters.

Comment: @XxJames07- OP says "...every character of a string inside the list...". That sounds to me like a list of strings. Maybe my English isn't as good as it could be

Comment: Question has been edited and now states: "so basically what i wanted to was that count strings" which makes no sense at all

Comment: Why the title is completely unrelated to the question?

Comment: Just needs one more close vote

Answer (score 1):

One approach to your problem would be:

1. get the unique characters in your string
2. count the occurrences of each character in the string

given the string:

```
my_str = "this is my string"
```

first get the unique characters:

```
my_list_of_unique_characters = list(set(my_str))
```

now iterate through your list and count the occurrences:

```
for character in my_list_of_unique_characters:
  number_occurrences = my_str.count(character)
  print("Occurrences of character " + character + " : " + str(number_occurrences))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think OP is looking for:

```
from collections import Counter

list_of_strings = ['banana', 'apple', 'grapefruit']

for str_ in list_of_strings:
    print(f'{str_}:')
    for k, v in Counter(str_).items():
        print('\t{} occurs {} time{}'.format(k, v, 's' if v > 1 else ''))
```

**Output:**

```
banana:
        b occurs 1 time
        a occurs 3 times
        n occurs 2 times
apple:
        a occurs 1 time
        p occurs 2 times
        l occurs 1 time
        e occurs 1 time
grapefruit:
        g occurs 1 time
        r occurs 2 times
        a occurs 1 time
        p occurs 1 time
        e occurs 1 time
        f occurs 1 time
        u occurs 1 time
        i occurs 1 time
        t occurs 1 time
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, suppose you have a list of strings:

```
a = ["BBAACCDD","E"]
```

To find each occurence inside a list I would advise to use the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module

```
 class collections.Counter([iterable-or-mapping])
```

> A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages.

```
>>> joined_str = ''.join(a)
>>> occurences = cc.Counter(joined_str)
>>> occurences
Counter({'B': 2, 'A': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 2, 'E': 1})
>>> #check with a filter if all occurences are even
>>> if all(filter(occurences.values(),lambda x:not x%2)):
...     print("All even numbers of occurences")
... else:
...     print("Not All even number of occurences")
Not All even number of occurences
```